# Adding left/right bars to letters

Tags: math-mode, graphics, symbols, text-decorations

Is there an equivalent of the top/bottom bars you can get with `\overbar`, `\underbar` but for left and right bars? I would like to have a small vertical bar right next to some text in mathmode.

I would prefer existing solutions in some package but a custom macro/command is also fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you point to some place where this notation is used or make some examples?

Comment: Do you mean something like `$|a|$`?

Comment: Which would be wrong in some cases `$\lvert -a \rvert \neq |-a|$`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question might have been answered already in the comments, here an example how one could use absolute values or at least the `|` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Should be in every document, if you write math 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
|a+b| \leq \left| a \right| + \lvert b \rvert 
\]

\[
\left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \;\middle|\; \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \right\}
=
\left\{ 2^n \;\middle|\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
\]

\[
|x| =
\begin{cases}
x  &\mathrm{if}\ x \geq 0\\
-x &\mathrm{if}\ x  <  0
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

As daleif pointed out, they might not be the same, but I think as long as you choose one and stick with it, it shouldn't be a problem. I recommend using `\left|`, `\middle|` and `\right|`, because LaTeX will automaticly adjust the height of `|`, the prefixes will also work with brackets, as you can see in my second example.

So here the output:

[image: Output of the example]

For future works, you may find this [site](http://kogler.wordpress.com/2008/03/23/latex-fine-tunning-and-some-extras/) handy. Have Fun!

Comment: The place where you say `\right|` is handy is *not* the best illustration; in that case one should prefer `\;\middle|\;` (removing the `\left.`), but this is still a different usage of the bar, because it's a relation symbol.

Comment: To my understanding the solution with `\lvert`/`\rvert` is not the same as witha `\left|`/`\right|` because the `\levert` and `\rvert` delimiters may have special positions for sub/superscripts.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the heads up, I always used it, like I wrote, but your solution seems way better than mine.